# Webpack: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm trying to expose one of my classes to global. However eslint tells me that "window" is undefined, It's not eslint problem because my class still not accessible even when I turn off eslint.

This is my webpack configuration:

```
export default {
  output: {
    filename: 'dist/client-bundle.js',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

I've also set `"env": { "browser": true }` in my `package.json` and I can see `window.myClass = className` in `client-bundle.js` but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing configuration to this solved the problem, Also one of the reason that globals were unaccessable was using `webpack-dev-server`.

```
export default {
  output: {
    filename: 'dist/client-bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'className'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```